# Loop through rows using Excel VBA to set a incrementing counter

Tags: vba, excel

The "REQUIRED" field is the one which needs populating,

- For each UNIQUE Serial "REQUIRED" Number incremented by 1 ONLY IF starred "*". in VBA.

This is what it should look like.

http://s2.postimg.org/nketog5t5/table.jpg

```
Serial Number   REQUIRED    Starred SEQ_NO
040846/Z/96/C   1   *   1
040846/Z/96/C   2   *   2
040846/Z/96/C           3
042190/Z/96/F   1   *   1
042368/Z/97/B   1   *   1
042368/Z/97/B           2
042368/Z/97/B   2   *   3
042368/Z/97/B           4
042368/Z/97/B   3   *   5
042368/Z/97/B           6
042368/Z/97/B           7
042368/Z/97/B           8
047608/Z/96/B   1   *   1
047608/Z/96/B           2
047675/Z/96/D   1   *   1
047675/Z/96/D   2   *   2
047675/Z/96/D           3
```

Comment: I don't think you need VBA for this.  I think you can accomplish it by using `COUNTIFS()` formula.

Comment: Can you please be a little more clear? You have incremented numbers on some values without a "*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this formula down the column you're trying to populate.  You can tweak it a little to hide the zeroes if you care about that.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$C$2:C2,"*")
```

Note the hard references vs. the relative references in that formula, and make sure your entries align with those.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
Sub increment()
Dim prevalue As String
Dim curvalue As String
Dim lstrow As Long, i As Long, j As Integer

lstrow = Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
j = 0

For i = 2 To lstrow
    curvalue = Range("A" & i).Value
    If curvalue = prevalue And Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value = "*" Then
        j = j + 1
        Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = j
    ElseIf curvalue <> prevalue And Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value = "*" Then
        j = 1
        Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = j
    End If
    prevalue = curvalue
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Very much so, thanks Nitish this code was very useful for me to learn how to do things like prevalue Offset which i wasn't sure how it was done.